# Notice: Array to string conversion in / Warning: Illegal offset type

Tags: php, arrays

Hello I have a code which occurs 2 errors in the first line.

Notice: Array to string conversion
and
Warning: Illegal offset type  ﻿

```
while (isset($config['group']) AND isset($config_file->$config['group']))
    {
        // Temporarily store config group name
        $group = $config['group'];
        unset($config['group']);

        // Add config group values, not overwriting existing keys
        $config += $config_file->$group;
    }
```

How can i Fix it?

Comment: You need braces: `$config_file->{$config['group']}`. Otherwise it's parsed as `($config_file->$config)['group']`

Comment: So the firest line should be while (isset($config['group']) AND isset($config_file->{$config['group']})) ??

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying